# How to limit number of filtered results in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm running Active Admin 1.0.0 on Rails 4.2 and I have a resource named `Contact`. Amongst others there is a field called `score`.

I would like to use the built in filter functionality on the Contact index page to allow a user to search for the `Contacts` with the top X (should be entered by the user) highest `score`.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nikhgupta.com/code/activeadmin/custom-filters-using-ransacker-in-activeadmin-interfaces/

Has a solution to this though using custom Ransack filters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`ActiveAdmin.register Contact do
  filter :contact, collection: proc { Contact.limit(top_users) }
  config.sort_order = 'score_desc'
end`

where 'top_users' is the user input.

Comment: That would only give me a dropdown to filter out one contact at the time amongst the `top_users`